# How to ensure if a MySQL backups are consistent?

Tags: mysql

How can we ensure if MySQL backups are consistent when they are in full backups as well as in incremental backups using binlogs. According to me, I just take random count(*) tables after issuing flush logs on the database. And take binlogs generated until that flushed binary file and ensuring the table is not altered while doing select count(*) . And then restore the binary logs in different database server and cross check count(*) for the random tables are same or not against prod db and restored db. Any other thoughts other than this? Keep in mind that hits from application to tables can be paused only for few mins.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-checksum.html). It's written for replication, but maybe you can adapt it for offline use with your master/restore server.

Comment: I don't think it can measure the Production live DB updating instance with restored silent DB instance in run time where it causes checksum differences always. Moreover I was looking for some options within mysql itself. I guess I will stand on my approach for the consistency check.